# One user can't run app

Tags: iphone

I have one user that can't run my iPhone app.  It starts up fine but crashes once they select a row in the RootViewController.  Selecting a row goes to another tableview.  I'm using sqlite in the app bundle and deploy on initial install if no db is available.  The db is there because the RootViewController wouldn't load otherwise.  I've tried a few troubleshooting steps with the user such as:

- Delete app from iPhone and resync with iTunes.
- Reboot iPhone.
- Confirm version of iPhone.

All of the above was tried to no avail.

I've not had any other user write in about such issues.  Has anyone had such an issue and have some possible suggestions on how to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would ask your user to delete the app from *both* the iPhone *and* iTunes and then reinstall it.  That will help ensure they aren't getting the data restored.

You may also want to make sure they haven't jailbroken their phone.  In general, I try to ask for a wide variety of information:

- Device type
- Device generation
- OS version
- Jailbreak status
- Language setting
- Region setting
- Whether they have WiFi, cellular Internet, and 3G on (I'd also ask about GPS if your app uses that)

Finally, iTunes may be stashing crash logs on their hard drive (on Macs it's under `~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice`; I don't know about Windows machines).  Ask your user to try to locate ones related to your app and send them to you.

Comment: Yep - it is jailbroken.  I know all bets are off but what about jailbroken would crash the app?

Comment: Who knows? Jailbreaking modifies several parts of the OS to break the security, and then they can do anything else they want. For all you know, something installed a buggy version of libsqlite or hacked UIKit to turn everything purple instead of blue or is running in the background eating memory.